# Parent and Child Regex Matches

Tags: html, regex, go

Regex has always been a weaker point for me, so I need some help.

I'm basically try to have opening and closing 'tags' with the same regex allowed on the inside of these tags.

So a tag may look like:
`<: tagname("[capture1]","[capture2]","[capture3]") :>[inner code]<: endtagname :>`

So one with child tags may be like:
`<: tagname("[capture1]","[capture2]","[capture3]") :>This is a tag: <: tagname("[capture1]","[capture2]","[capture3]") :>[inner code]<: endtagname :> that was a tag<: endtagname :>`

So I've tried a few regex codes, but cannot figure out how to get the parent tag not to end on the child tag.

So here is one of the regex expressions that I've tried:
`<:[ ]?date[ ]?[(][ ]?'"['"],[ ]?'"['"],[ ]?'"['"][)][ ]?:>([\s\S\t\r]*)<:[ ]?enddate[ ]?:>`

This works for single level tags, but not for parent/child tags.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without recursion or balanced constructs, you cannot handle it with a regex. Go regex has none. A dedicated parser seems to be the only way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said in comment, build your parser.
Here you've got examples (next answer), and some more resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422952/6107031